# MIMEMultipart Python : Correos sin asunto y sin adjunto

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

estoy haciendo una funcionalidad para enviar correos desde Python con SMTPLib, el código ya envía correo y todo parece funcionar normal, no obstante, el correo llega sin asunto y sin el archivo que se supone estoy adjuntando.

No me aparece error al codificar el archivo, todo funciona corrrecto, solo que no inclue el archivo ni el asunto, he buscado en cantidad de foros sin embargo al parecer nadie a preguntado sobre un caso similar.

El correo que recibo llega de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy usando lo tengo así: (Los parámetros están llegando correctamente)

```py
from smtplib import SMTP
from os import getenv, path

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

class Email:
    def __init__(self):
        load_dotenv("./model/")
        self.server = SMTP(
            host=getenv('SMTP_HOST'),
            port=getenv('SMTP_TLS_PORT')
        )

    def conect_server(self):
        self.server.starttls()
        self.server.login(
            user=getenv('EMAIL_SENDER'),
            password=getenv('PASSWORD_SENDER')
        )
    
    def send_email(self, data):
        self.conect_server()
        print ("[ENVIANDO EMAIL.....]")
        email = data['recipient']
        fileSend = data['attach']
        
        header = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
        header['Subject'] = data['subject']
        header['From'] = getenv('EMAIL_SENDER')
        header['To'] = email
        
        message = MIMEText(data['bodyMessage'], 'html')
        header.attach(message)
        
        if path.isfile(fileSend):
            file = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            file.set_payload(open(fileSend, 'rb').read())
            encoders.encode_base64(file)
            file.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % fileSend)
            header.attach(fileSend)
        else:
            print ("[ARCHIVO NO VALIDO..!]")
            
            
        try:
            self.server.sendmail(getenv('EMAIL_SENDER'),email, header.as_string())
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error encontrado: {e}")
        finally:
            self.disconect_server()            
    
    def disconect_server(self):
        self.server.quit()
        self.server.close()
```

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar a encontrar que estoy realizando mal. Necesito lograr que llegue el archivo adjunto (Excel), y que llegue con el asunto que le estoy enviando.

Comment: La variable `headers` solo recibe valores, pero nunca la envias o incluyes en el mensaje.

Comment: @CandidMoe gracias por tu comentario, sin embargo al intentar realizar `header.as_string()` y adjuntarlo en el correo, me aparece un error `'str' object has no attribute 'policy'` Faltará alguna librería por importar?...

Comment: Si no usas `header` en ninguna parte, ¿cómo esperas que su contenido aparezca?

Comment: @CandidMoe si de hecho es la variable que instancia a `MIMEMultipart('alternative')`  Permiteme voy a actualizar el código de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Luego de mucho buscar y recibir comentarios en las diferentes comunidades, logré solucionar el inconveniente.

Pasaba que estaba adjuntando al email, la variable que recibe el nombre del archivo a adjuntar, no obstante no estaba adjuntando el archivo codificado en base64. Mostraré donde realicé el cambio para corregir el fallo.

```py
from os import path
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def send_email(self, data): 
    #...... 
    self.fileSend = data['attach']
    
    self.header = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    
    #.......
    if path.isfile(self.fileSend):
        file = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        file.set_payload(open(self.fileSend, 'rb').read())
        encoders.encode_base64(file)
        file.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % self.fileSend)
        self.header.attach(file)
        
    #.......................
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solventó el error que presentaba.

Comment: Debieras marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. :)